# Desktop version of/front-end to Google Translate

Tags: windows, translation

With Google Translate, I can hold my Android 'phone and translate any text which the camera can see:

[image]

Now,  I have a bunch of Chinese user manuals and would like to scan them in and have Google translate them for me.  I do not know how to type the Chinese characters into the Google Translate  web site, and the pages are too large and too numerous to use my 'phone.

Any ideas?

---

[Update] Translator from the Microsoft app store looked very promising,a nd may well work or other languages.

Alsas, from Chinese, it produced

> Hu Nao 0 0 kang, 0 @ small @ Chong Lei, kohlrabi speaking  , 0 body
>   and 0 kohlrabi  30 places  0 Conocephalidae is born and Jiao 0 of 0
>   00,  Not the drawers, the FIR and the heart fly  0 to dictated black
>   corpses.  : Back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Translate website allows you to upload documents as well as typing in text, you could also run an Android emulator and run the android app to translate images of the manual pages

Comment: All that I can say to that is "D'oh!" :-) Thank you so much for pointing out the glaringly obvious. You have saved my freinds in Hong Kong & Singapore a lot of work :-)

Comment: Hmmm, Google translate allows me to upload a "document", but I am not sure about an image. However, the Android emulator will do the trick